# Restrict user to allow only 10 digit number in input box

Tags: angularjs

I just want to restrict user to input only 10 digits in a mobile number field.
I have tried this code

```
 app.directive('allowOnlyNumbers', function () {  
        return {  
            restrict: 'A',  
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {  
                elm.on('keydown', function (event) {  
                    if (event.which == 64 || event.which == 16) {  
                        // to allow numbers  
                        return false;  
                    } else if (event.which >= 48 && event.which <= 57) {  
                        // to allow numbers  
                        return true;  
                    } else if (event.which >= 96 && event.which <= 105) {  
                        // to allow numpad number  
                        return true;  
                    } else if ([8, 13, 27, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.which) > -1) {  
                        // to allow backspace, enter, escape, arrows  
                        return true;  
                    } else {  
                        event.preventDefault();  
                        // to stop others  
                        return false;  
                    }  
                });  
            }  
        }  
    });
```

This code allow users to input the numbers but it's taking more than 10 digits.
can anyone tell me how to restrict ofr only 10 digits only?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 3):

Just use  **`maxlength`** attribute without directive

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sample" maxlength="10">
```

**EDIT**
Change it to type="number" if you want to have only numbers,

```
 <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="sample" maxlength="10">
```

Comment: how does this restrict you to using only numbers?

Comment: @ippi i think this is what op is looking for, just making type=number would solve

Comment: After reading the question again I think you are right. Sorry.

Comment: @user6891871 did the answer help?

Answer (score 3):

You could also try using `ng-pattern`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="sample"
       ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/">
```

This would require exactly 10 digits, and nothing else, for validation to pass.  If you instead require a maximum of 10 digits, but fewer digits than this also acceptable, then you could use `^[0-9]{1,10}`.